# Include Post Format in permalink

Tags: permalinks, post-formats

I'm running the latest version of WordPress with pretty permalinks enabled.

I'm looking for a way to include the Post Format type (eg: link, status, quote) in the post's permalink. When the post has no format assigned, or uses the 'standard' format, I want that part of the permalink to empty.

Example using the link post format:

```
http://example.com/link/look-at-this-cool-site/
```

Example using the quote post format:

```
http://example.com/quote/example-quote-post
```

Example using no post format:

```
http://example.com/just-another-post
```

**Edit:** See [my answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/71362/19726) for progress

Comment: do child attachment post URLs still need to function? for example `/link/look-at-this-cool-site/attachment-post/` or `/just-another-post/attachment-post/`

Comment: @Milo Yes, they would. Just as if you were using `%category%` as part of your permalink structure.

Comment: the one thing that makes it vastly more complicated is your requirement to have no format for posts without a format, that's not how %category% permalinks work, so it's not quite the same. without a format, your posts would clash with pages, or you'll need extra rewrite rules and some fairly complex parsing to make attachment posts work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While researching this topic myself, I found a plugin called [Post Format Permalink](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-format-permalink/). However, this plugin is not compatible with recent versions of WordPress; it is also filled with unnecessary code.

I [forked](https://github.com/bungeshea/post-format-permalink) the plugin's [repository](https://github.com/statikpulse/post-format-permalink) on GitHub, and improved the code greatly. I can now use a `%post_format%` tag in my permalink structure, and that works fine. Mostly.

The problem is, posts with no post format are displaying as `http://example.com/standard/just-another-post`, which is not the desired outcome. I'll keep working on this, and post an update here.

Here is the code I used. It can also be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/sheabunge/post-format-permalink):

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Post Format Permalink
 * Plugin URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/70627/19726
 * Description: Include the post format slug in your permalinks. Simply use the <code>%post_format%</code> tag as part of your custom permalink.
 * Version: 1.2
 * Author: shea
 * Author URI: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/19726
 */

add_filter( 'post_link', 'post_format_permalink', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'post_format_permalink', 10, 2 );

function post_format_permalink( $permalink, $post_id ) {

    // if we're not using the %post_format% tag in our permalinks, bail early
    if ( strpos($permalink, '%post_format%') === FALSE ) return $permalink;

    // get the post object
    $post = get_post( $post_id );
    if ( ! $post ) return $permalink;

    // get post format slug
    $format = get_post_format( $post->ID );

    // set the slug for standard posts
    if ( empty( $format ) )
        $format = apply_filters( 'post_format_standard_slug', 'standard' );

    // apply the post format slug to the permalink
    return str_replace( '%post_format%', $format, $permalink );
}
```

Comment: Great solution, but it appears to be causing an issue for permalinks for pages. All pages are giving a 404 not found. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: @Dustin I just tried it out again, and you're right. It was working fine when I wrote this snippet, I'll try and see what is causing it to break

Answer (score -1):

You can add a custom slug to the permalinks via plugin and use this inside your custom permalinks; dont forgett to update the permalinks. It is important, that the rules was refreshed. The follow source is a exmaple for use post format with the string `%postformat%`, but not perfectly code. Better is to load on hook `plugins_loaded` and not create a new class, but enough to test and use it now.

Please check this, current untested. I have write this for long time.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Post Format Permalink
 * Description: Allow to use Post Format as Permalink; inlcude %postformat% in custom permalink
 */

class Fb_Add_Post_Format_Permalink {

    function __construct() {

        add_filter( 'pre_post_link', array( $this, 'generate_permalink' ), 10, 2 );
        add_filter( 'post_rewrite_rules', array( $this, 'rewrite_rules' ) );
        add_filter( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array( $this, 'generate_rewrite_rules' ) );
    }

    function generate_permalink( $permalink, $post ) {
        global $standard_slug;

        if ( FALSE === strpos( $permalink, '%postformat%' ) )
            return $permalink;

        if ( ! is_object( $post ) )
            $post = get_post( $post_id );

        $postformat = get_post_format( $post->ID );
        if ( empty( $postformat ) )
            $postformat = ! empty($standard_slug) ? $standard_slug : 'standard';

        return str_replace( '%postformat%', $postformat, $permalink );
    }

    function generate_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
        global $clean_post_rewrites;

        $wp_rewrite->rules = $wp_rewrite->rules + $clean_post_rewrites;
    }

    function rewrite_rules( $post_rewrite ) {
        global $clean_post_rewrites, $wp_rewrite, $standard_slug;

        $wp_rewrite->use_verbose_page_rules = TRUE;

        $post_format_slugs = implode( '|', get_post_format_slugs() );
        if ( ! empty($standard_slug) )
            $post_format_slugs = preg_replace( '|standard|', $standard_slug, $post_format_slugs, 1 );

        while ( list($k, $v) = each( $post_rewrite ) ) {
            $new_k = preg_replace( '|%postformat%|', '(' . $post_format_slugs . ')', $k, 1 );
            $clean_post_rewrites[$new_k] = $v;
        }

        return $post_rewrite;
    }

}
$post_format = new Fb_Add_Post_Format_Permalink();
```

Comment: Sorry, that code does not work on my setup

Comment: You have a error or nothing?

Comment: Permalinks appear to be `http://example.com/%postformat%/example-quote-post`

Comment: Is the other solution not the right solution for you?

Comment: Hint: you can change the string of Permalink for post format in the other answer via Filter ´post_format_standard_slug` or you change this in your code; remove the lines `    // set the slug for standard posts
    if ( empty( $format ) )
        $format = apply_filters( 'post_format_standard_slug', 'standard' );` and the permalinks is only inlcude the post format, if the post have a post format. Is this, what you want. see this [Gist 4017182](https://gist.github.com/4017182) for download the solution.

Comment: Removing that line generates permalinks like `http://example.com//just-another-post` for posts with no format, and I get 404 errors for those posts.

Comment: OK, I have tested with the / on the end; but then it is important, that we check on source, if is the standard post format, then remove the double /.

Comment: Maybe the htaccess entry helps? `# forbid double slashes in all URLs
<Ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(([^/\ ]+/)*)/+([^\ ]*)
  RewriteRule ^ /%1%3 [L,R=301]
</Ifmodule>`

Comment: I'm still getting 404 errors

Comment: You have right; I think, the system must use a string :( Maybe you can use a "light" string, like `-` ? Not perfectly, but I have not a solution for this part.

Comment: Well, I appreciate that you were willing to help, so you can have the bounty.

Comment: :) Thanks a lot; but I don't have a solution for this problem and current no idea to solve this.

Comment: But, last idea as topic here. I think, there is possible, that the standard post format must via hook `generate_rewrite_rules` a custom url, only then is it possible to use this.

Comment: When the post_format taxonomy is created, it automatically generates a rewrite tag and permastruct.
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L358